Why is UIVisualEffectView not working on device
I'm trying to add a UIVisualEffectView to my project but it's not showing properly so I've created a basic test as below.. it appears to be fine in the storyboard and also the simulator but why does the effect view show as a grey rectangle on my iPhone 15 Pro?



I feel like someone is holding the blurview until I see third screenshot of the app...

It's because on your phone you've turned on Reduce Transparency.

